# How to inject dependency in a usercontrol on a winform

Tags: winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a winform which contains a usercontrol. That usercontrol has a dependency which I need to resolve using unity. The problem with using constructor injection is that the user control is instantiated in the InitializeComponent of the designer of the winform. Hence I cannot place container.Resolve over there.

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will want to use Property Injection and BuildUp:

[Using BuildUp to Wire Up Objects Not Created by the Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Constructor injection is generally the preferred method, but as you noted it's not possible when dealing with WinForm controls.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a snippet? For the example, you can assume that the winform is TestWinform, usercontrol is TestUserControl, the property on the usercontrol is ITestInferface that is registered against TestClass in the container. Snippet in VB would be highly appreciated, although C# would also work